# Определение типа без switch

Tags: golang, типы-данных

Мне нужно определить, что значение является типом `[]interface{}` не используя switch(как по мне, эта конструкция слишком громоздка для такой частой и простой задачи).

Вроде нашел решение в методе `reflect.TypeOf`:

```
if reflect.TypeOf(val) == reflect.TypeOf([]interface{}{}) {
}
```

Здесь, `TypeOf` определяет тип моего значения и нужного мне типа, а затем сравнивает результат обоих `TypeOf`. Проблема в том, что я плохо знаю go, и поэтому не уверен в данном варианте.

Собственно вопрос: какие есть подводные камни в данном решении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему не использовать простое утверждение типа (англ «*type
assertion*»)?

```golang
_, ok := val.([]interface{})
```

Comment: Спасибо! Не знал, что так можно делать )